# How do I cast between subclasses of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm subclassing `std::shared_ptr` and am trying to write a `cast()` method on the subclass so I can hide `static_pointer_cast`, but I can't get my code to compile. What am I missing?

Demo: http://ideone.com/nbPHbs

```cpp
template<class T>
class Handle : public std::shared_ptr<T> {
public:
    template<class ResultType>
    inline Handle<ResultType>
    cast() {
        // Cast Handle to shared_ptr
        auto T_sp = static_cast< std::shared_ptr<T> >(*this);
        // Cast the data
        auto ResultType_sp = std::static_pointer_cast<ResultType>(T_sp);
        // Cast back to Handle
        return static_cast< Handle<ResultType> >(ResultType_sp);
    }
};


// Usage
struct Base {};
struct Child : public Base {};
auto child_ptr = Handle<Child>(new Child());
auto base_ptr  = child_ptr.cast<Base>(); // Error with this
```

This is the Error message I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Handle<Child>::Handle(Child*)'
auto child_ptr = Handle<Child>(new Child());
                                         ^
```

**EDIT
I'm using inheritance here because it was write-once/throw-away code that was originally `template<T> using std::shared_ptr<T> Handle<T>;` So, inheritance was the natural progression that required the least amount of code changes. Since it did look like this piece of code will stick around a little longer, I did switch to composition before posting this SO question, I just wanted to know why it wasn't compiling; I haven't done any c++ in a few years, so my skills are a little rusty.

Comment: Your class has no constructor, the error message you show is not related to the line 'Error with this'. Apart from that it seems like a bad idea deriving from shared_ptr, what you want could be done with a free function instead.

Comment: Be careful. the `std::shared_ptr` [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr) is not virtual.

Comment: _"I'm subclassing std::shared_ptr ..."_ You shouldn't do this. Classes from the `std` namespace are usually not intended to be inherited.

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited. And you shouldn't subclass `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I dont see any advantage of inheriting shared_ptr here, its not worth the trouble imho. if you think `std::static_pointer_cast` is big and ugly, you can solve that by an inline function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is skipping the discussion as to whether inheriting from std::shared_ptr is a good idea or not. I would though recommend reading such discussion before continuing further.

***Now to your immediate problem:***

If you really want to continue this route then what you are missing is the constructors.
The compiler is only creating a default constructor for you.
As the error message shows you need `Handle<Child>::Handle(Child*)`.

The easiest way to get the needed constructors would be to reuse the ones from the base class:

```
template<class T>
class Handle : public std::shared_ptr<T> {
public:
    using std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought was the problem; but it's been such a long time since I've done c++ that I couldn't remember the rules for inheriting methods. RE: inheriting; See edit in original question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any advantage of inheriting shared_ptr here, its not worth the trouble imho. if you think std::static_pointer_cast is big and ugly, you can solve that by an inline function

```
template <typename TOUT, typename TIN>
inline std::shared_ptr<TOUT> cast(TIN in)
{
    return std::static_pointer_cast<TOUT>(in);
}

// Usage
struct Base {};
struct Child : public Base {};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Child> child_ptr = std::make_shared<Child>();
    std::shared_ptr<Base> base_ptr  = cast<Base>(child_ptr); // Error with this
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your class does not have any constructor, therefore, when you try to compile, it will miserably fail if you try to use a constructor with arguments.

*If you wanted* to inherit from `shared_ptr` (which I disencourage, because base destructor is not virtual and your program most likely will leak memory heavily) you should add this line in your class body:

```
using std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;
```

Comment: UB would only be a problem if someone heap allocates Handle, then deletes it through a pointer to shared ptr.  Unlikely.  There are good reasons not to subclass: in this narrow case, the lack of virtual dtor is not one of them.